# How to install gss-ntlmssp with yum?

Tags: linux, yum, rhel, alpine-linux

We have the requirement to install gss-ntlmssp using yum  .I also tried to insatll the prerequisites as mentioned in the online channel but it does not help out either .
I tried to run the command :

```
RUN yum -y install https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-8.noarch.rpm
RUN yum install gssntlmssp


Error: Unable to find a match: gssntlmssp
The command '/bin/sh -c yum -y install gssntlmssp' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Please let me know how can this be resolved .

Answer (score 0):

The command you search for is

```
RUN yum -y localinstall https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-8.noarch.rpm
```

This will download and install the package and prerequisites (if they found in defined repos on the machine)